# use drupal's hashing in an external php file

Tags: drupal-7

we are making a few web services for a Drupal 7 based websites.
in that webservice, one task is to sign up new users on that website.

the only main issue at the moment for this task is to access the drupal hash function in a php code file that is not inside the drupal's installation directory.

any guidance on how to achieve this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any issue with exposing the service via Drupal directly? Perhaps via the [services module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services).

If you really need it to be external, suggest to still expose the registration service via services, and implement your external service as a wrapper.

Comment: thank you for the answer. have tried to follow your advice . but now can you help with the following issue :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489308/implementing-user-has-password-in-hook-menu