# implementing user has password in hook menu

Tags: php, drupal-7

we are implementing a web service for a Drupal 7 site (the web service code is not part of drupal installation folder).

one of the web services needs to sign up the user on the site. 
the main hurdle was getting  a hashed password that Drupal will also recognize.

for that , am following a suggestion made on stack overflow to Implement a REST service inside drupal and call that from the outside service code . (that part also seems possible and achieveable).

have implemented a password hashing service with following code:

```
function GetHashedPassword($string)
{
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('password_inc', 'includes/password.inc');

    $hashedpw = user_hash_password($string);

    $data = array(
        'password' => $hashedpw
    );

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    drupal_json_output($data);
    drupal_exit();
}
```

the main issue now is that whenever this service is called even with same string , it returns a new hashed value each time..

kindly assist if what we need is actually even possible and if so, then what could be fixed in the above code

any help appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to create a user in Drupal or in the external system? My previous suggestion was actually for your external service to trigger perhaps a custom module in Drupal to create the user, and return a id or the full user json back to your external script. Perhaps you can explain more about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: yes thats what we did. implemented a REST service in drupal using hook_menu and called it in the external code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Drupal [user_hash_password](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_hash_password/7) function generates a new salt each time it calculates the hash. This will cause a new hash to be generated since the salt is likely to be different to the last one.

Comment: thank you for the answer. the user seems to login fine